# Override FilesMatch rule of root htaccess by htaccess from subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

There is a main website powered by CMS Drupal. Among its root directories there is the directory `shop` where another (child) website is located and it's also powered by Drupal.

Both the websites have their root `.htaccess` files with the same rule like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config)$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

In the theme directory of the second (child) website I created my own custom `.htaccess` file to deny access to two files inside the theme:

```
<FilesMatch "(products.json|README.md)">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

And it works fine.

Now I need to allow access to file called `cell.html.twig` inside the same theme directory. But the `.twig` extension is denied by the rule of both root `.htaccess` files I mentioned above.

So how can I override the root rule in order to allow access to my twig file in my custom `.htaccess` inside the theme? I mean without changing the root `.htaccess` (if it's possible).

If I add the rule to my custom theme `.htaccess` like

```
<Files cell.html.twig>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

it doesn't help - the access to the file is still denied

---

**CLOSED**

Ok, I've just found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52791920/3208225